# Struts 2 radio button list

Tags: java, jsp, struts2, ognl, valuestack

am working on Struts 2 radio button.
I want to retrieve the list from my action class but it is giving following error

> org.apache.jasper.JasperException: tag
>   'radio', field 'list', name
>   'user.yourGender': The requested list
>   key '#user.gender' could not be
>   resolved as a
>   collection/array/map/enumeration/iterator
>   type. Example: people or people.{name}
>   - [unknown location]

my action class & user class is as follow

**`HelloAction`**

```
package com.geekcap.struts2.action;

import com.geekcap.struts2.model.User;
import com.opensymphony.xwork2.ActionSupport;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class HelloAction extends ActionSupport
{
 private User user;  

 public String execute() throws Exception
 {    
  return "success";
 }

 public void validate()
 {
  if(user.getName().length()==0)
  {
   addFieldError("user.name", "User Name is required");
  }

  if(user.getAge()==0)
  {
   addFieldError("user.age","Age is required");
  }

  if(user.getPassword().length()==0)
  {
   addFieldError("user.password","Please enter your password !");
  }

 /* if(user.getGender().equals("-1"))
  {
   addFieldError("user.gender","Please select gender !");
  }*/
 }



 public User getUser()
 {
  return user;
 }

 public void setUser(User userbean)
 {
  user=userbean;
 }

}
```

**User class**

```
package com.geekcap.struts2.model;

import java.util.List;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class User
{
 private String name,password;
// private List like;
 private int age;
 private List<String> gender;
 private String yourGender;

 public User()
 {
  gender= new ArrayList<String>();
  gender.add("MALE");
  gender.add("FEMALE");
  gender.add("UNKNOWN");
 }


 public String getName() 
 {
  return name;
 }

 public void setName(String name) 
 {
  this.name = name;
 }

 public String getPassword()
 {
  return password;
 }

 public void setPassword(String password)
 {
  this.password=password;
 }

 public int getAge()
 {
  return age;
 }

 public void setAge(int age)
 {
  this.age=age;
 }

 public List<String> getGender()
 {
  return gender;
 }

 public void setGender(List<String> gender)
 {
  this.gender=gender;
 }

 public void setYourGender(String yourGender)
 {
  this.yourGender=yourGender;
 }

 public String getYourGender()
 {
  return  yourGender;
 }

 public String getDefaultGenderValue()
 {
  return "UNKNOWN";
 }
```

**helloForm.jsp**

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8"pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="s" uri="/struts-tags" %>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<title>Welcome to Struts 2</title>
</head>
<body>

<s:form action="Hello"> 
  <s:textfield name="user.name" label="User name" value="shahid"/>
  <s:password name="user.password" label="Password"/>
  <s:textfield name="user.age" label="Age"/>    
  <s:radio label="Gender" name="user.yourGender" list="user.gender" value="defaultGenderValue"/>     
  <s:submit/>
</s:form>

</body>
</html>
```

**hello.jsp**

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8"
  pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="s" uri="/struts-tags" %>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<title>Hello, Struts 2</title>
</head>
<body>
<h4>
Hello, <s:property value="user.name"/>!
<br>Your password :<s:property value="user.password"/></br>
<br>your age :<s:property value="user.age"/></br>
<br>Gender :<s:property value="user.yourGender"/></br>
</h4> 
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: it'll be helpful if you can format your question better [hint: use the 'code' formatter]. what's the html code you're using for the radio buttons?

Comment: as anirvan said use the code formatter button (the one labelled as 1010) to format code. I have done it for you this time.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure the list `gender` is NOT `null` in the JSP?

If it is null, then struts will not see it and therefore think it isn't there

Comment: no it is not null,in fact i have generated the list for radio in user action constructor

Comment: @user541595 You say that you have generated the list. but in the action class example, you have not shown that. Make sure your list is instantiated and populated before this particular JSP. You might want to print/debug it at the end of the action class to be sure.